# “Both you and he are very happy” or "Both you and him are very happy"？

Tags: pronouns, formality, coordination, case

It's a sentence on a test paper:

> Both you and he are very happy.

The sentence itself sounds awkward. Let's cast the awkwardness aside and look into the grammar. It's understandable that as part of the subject, "he" is the correct pronoun form. But I still wonder if "him" can be used anyway. We usually say "you and me" whatever the case, don't we?

Comment: This can be helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/5361/124070

Comment: *"We usually say "you and me" whatever the case, don't we?"*  No, there are many cases where we say "You and I".  For example, "You and I went to the store."  You wouldn't say "Me went to the store", so you don't say "You and me went to the store."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always split the sentence in such dilemma. Make those two people in concern separate and check what works!

> You will go to London + <del>***Me***</del> I will go to London. **SO**, *You and **I** will go to London.*
>
> She'll meet you + She will meet <del>***I***</del> me. **SO,** *She'll meet you and **me***.

Take your sentence:

> *Both you and he are happy* = You are happy + He is happy ~ Yes!
>
> *Both you and him are happy* = You are happy + Him is happy ~ no, no!

And therefore, *"We usually say 'You and me' in <del>whatever</del> cases as mentioned above."*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both you and native speakers can say "Both you and him are very happy." This would not accord with standard grammar or formal usage, but not everything we write and say does.