# 'Yours and mine' or 'Your and my'?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects

I'm pretty clear about using subject or object version of pronouns.

While writing a line, I naturally wrote it in this way -

> ***Your and my** grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music.*

But then, as I read, it looked incorrect. Then I tried this:

> ***Yours and mine** grandparents had grown . . . "*

It looked even worse!

These are possessive cases, but still I'm confused what to use and **why?**

What confuses me is my [own rule of breaking the sentence in two and decide what fits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72579/both-you-and-he-are-very-happy-or-both-you-and-him-are-very-happy/72588#72588). If I break, it appears that . . .

> Your grandparents + my grandparents = *Your and my grandparents had . . . *

What if I use possessive pronoun 'yours' this way?

> *"The grandparents of **yours and mine** had grown up . . . "*

'yours' is used when the speaker refers to 'your things'. But then this particular sentence is baffling me! Because I'm the speaker and the sentence includes my possession as well!

---

Okay, we have ***'our'*** as ***'you'*** and ***'I'***, but then the question is about using proper pronouns.

What if you tried this:

> *Your and her grandparents...*

Or...

> *Yours and her grandparents...*

Or...

> *Yours and hers grandparents...*

Comment: can it be ***Your grandparents and mine had grown listening to this piece of music.*** ???

Comment: True, but I want to emphasize your/mine @XPMai Check: 'we'll decide what happens next' over 'You and I decide what happens next'. The latter one has some weightage! :)

Comment: @Usernew to me, putting the noun after the second pronoun is more clear.

Comment: @MaulikV, I don't understand what you're saying. *"You and I"* are **pronouns** while *"your and my"* are **possessive adjectives**. Therefore, your example doesn't prove anything.

Comment: 'Your' is possessive adjective; 'yours' is possessive pronoun @XPMai my examples are *not* to prove anything, they are the questions!

Comment: @MaulikV, I'm referring to the examples in the comment that you given me.

Comment: @MaulikV Did a google check, and it gives the following result: 2,88,000 results for "your and my parents," 2,02,000 for "your parents and mine," and 240 for "yours and my parents." [Result of Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your+and+my+parents%2Cyours+and+mine+parents%2Cyour+parents+and+mine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20parents%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0) on the other hand

Comment: Given that, It would be right to say ***Your and my grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music.*** even though if it looks incorrect.

Comment: ... slightly off topic but why use "had grown" instead of "grew"? "Your grandparents, and mine, grew **up** listening to this piece of music." "Had grown" makes them seem like they magically got young again.

Comment: ***Your and my grandparents*** is perfectly acceptable, but indeed weird. I think it's as far as you'll be able to get with explicitly using both possessive pron.s. I wonder why you don't want to use "our": ***Our grandparents . . .***

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Of course, 'our' is common but that does not mean 'you and I' doesn't exist, does it?

Comment: Well, the reason you're feeling uneasy with 'you and I' or other similar pairs is that the pronoun seems *parted* with the head.

Comment: Nice question!  I think it should remain open.

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is confusing because you're using *your and my* when we already have a word *our* which would normally be preferred. For this reason the sentence is a little awkward, because it's not really clear why the writer has decided to not use *our* here.

If you want to use *your and my* for emphasis, which you certainly could do, then it would be a good idea to use the marker *both* here to highlight this:

> Both your and my grandparents grew up listening to this piece of music.

This sounds perfectly natural and correct.

With regards to *yours and mine*, this is ungrammatical. The reason for this is that in modern English we never use *mine* or *yours* when there is a following noun.

- It's my elephant.
- It's mine.
- *It's mine elephant. (ungrammatical in modern English)

I think your last sentence is a bit awkward because there doesn't seem to be any benefit in terms of meaning or effect for using such a complex construction when *our grandparents* would seem to do the same job.

Comment: We have word 'our' but does it mean that 'you and I' can't be used? [Gaga](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kqQDCxRCzM) and I'll be disappointed then!

Comment: @MaulikV No, but there needs to be a reason for doing so, that's all. For example, in you and Gaga, Gaga is needed to explain who the other person is. In "you and I get on well" the "you" and "I" have a contrastive effect where you're emphasising the identity of each other :)

Comment: I wonder why do we discuss the 'example' and not focus on the question about **using** proper possessive pronouns which is confusing.

Comment: @Maulik I'm confused about why you're confused. We can't use *mine*, *yours* etc with a following noun. That's the important point.

Comment: The confusion occurred as *Anisya Fedorovna's smiling face reappeared in the doorway and behind **hers other faces**...* looked okay to me. Added to the question. So, it's not about one particular example, it's the use of a possessive pronoun.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the last sentence so that it remains clear and not confusing. Thank you.

Comment: @MaulikV "hers other faces" would be greatly aided by adding a comma: "behind hers, other faces".

Comment: "our" introduces an ambiguity, unless it has been established that the speaker and listener are not cousins.

Comment: Parallel structure should be followed in this example.  It's better to say "Both your grandparents and my grandparents...."

Answer (score 1):

English is not my mother language but I will tell you my opinion!

In 'Syntax and Grammar of English Language' of P. Koutsoumpos I found the following :

**Possessive adjectives**

That is **my** pencil.
That is **your** pencil.
That is **his** pencil.
That is **its** pencil.
That is **our** pencil.
That is **their** pencil.

The words my, your, his, her, its, our and their are possessive adjectives.

**Possessive pronouns**

That pencil is **mine**.
That pencil is **yours**.
That pencil is **his**.
That pencil is **hers**.
That pencil is **its**.
That pencil is **ours**.
That pencil is **theirs**.

The words mine, yours, his, hers, its ours and theirs are possessive pronouns.

"Grow" is a verb! "Grow up" is a phrasal verb! "Grow" and "grow up" have different meanings!

We use "grow" to talk about something getting physically bigger or longer. We can say "My grass is growing" or "My bank account is growing" or "Does your hair grow fast or does it grow slowly?" or "What is the best way to grow a business fast?" or "What should I do if I need to grow my bank account?"

We use "grow up" only to talk about people becoming more mature. Using "grow up" implies that the thing is human. We can say "Where did you grow up?" or "What movies were popular when you were growing up?" or "What was your favorite meal as a kid growing up?" or "What is the best thing about watching your niece grow up?".

"Your and my grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music."This phrase is wrong!

"Both your and my grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music." This phrase is also wrong!

"Your grandparents and mine had grown up listening to this piece of music" or "My grandparents and yours had grown up listening to this piece of music". These phrases are correct! You cannot write "had grown" in these phrases. It would be wrong! We always say "had grown up"!

"They are mine grandparents" or "They are yours grandparents". These phrases are wrong! We cannot use mine or yours when there is a following noun!

"Yours and mine grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music." This phrase is wrong! In English we say:'' These grandparents are mine'' or "These grandparents are yours".

"The grandparents of yours and mine had grown up listening to this piece of music." This phrase is wrong!They say:"Our grandparents had grown up listening to this piece of music. "

"Your and her grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music."This phrase is wrong!They say:"Their grandparents had grown up listening to this piece of music. "

"Yours and her grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music." This phrase is wrong!

" Yours and hers grandparents had grown listening to this piece of music."This phrase is wrong!

" Your and Elizabeth's experience was entirely different."This phrase is wrong! We can say:"Your and Elizabeth's experiences was entirely different" or "Elizabeth's and your experiences was entirely different".This phrase refers to the present. In this phrase we can also use "are" to refer to the present. We can say:"Elizabeth's and your experiences are entirely different". We can also use "were"  to refer to the past. We can say:"Elizabeth's and your experiences were entirely different".

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is interesting but the example of 'our' as an alternative does not address the problem.
'Your and Elizabeth's experience was entirely different'
is obviously correct using the possessive adjective 'your'.