# "My and her" or "mine and her"

Tags: possessives

I would like to simultaneously introduce my thesis partner Lisa and refer to our thesis. I.e. summarise the following in one sentence:

> I conducted a thesis project with Lisa. As outlined in our thesis, ...

What is correct:

> As outlined in mine and her thesis...
>
> As outlined in mine and Lisa's thesis...

or

> As outlined in my and her thesis...
>
> As outlined in my and Lisa's thesis...

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72663/yours-and-mine-or-your-and-my) is similar but has a different order and the suggestion is to instead use "our" which is not applicable in my case.

Comment: Why is 'our' not applicable here - it is the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you and Lisa each wrote a thesis, or whether you wrote one thesis jointly?

Comment: @MikeBrockington this is the first (and last) time I introduce Lisa in the text.

Comment: @JavaLatte I added a bit more information for the use case, hopefully this clarifies what I intend.

Comment: If you collaborated on the thesis, 'our' is applicable.

Comment: This is one of those constructions natives avoid, because even if they get it right they’re **still** not absolutely sure they did. **Our** just saves all the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, [mine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mine) is a pronoun, and refers back to something already mentioned... and [my](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/my) is a determiner, which must be followed by the thing that's yours.

> 1) How's your **thesis** going? I've nearly finished **mine**.
>
> 2) I have nearly finished **my** **thesis**.

So, if you say

> As outlined in mine and Lisa's thesis

**mine** refers back to something already mentioned: not a thesis, otherwise you could say "mine and Lisa's." - maybe a dissertation. So you are referring to your dissertation and Lisa's thesis.

> As outlined in my and her thesis

**her** refers to somebody that you have already mentioned or the listener already knows about. Writing **my and her** sounds like you are talking about two separate theses. If it's just one thesis that you jointly wrote,it would be better to say **our**.

Note that it is conventional to put your own pronoun last- in this case **her and my**.

> As outlined in my and Lisa's thesis

This would work if Lisa had not already been mentioned. You can't say **our** because the listener doesn't know who you are talking about yet. You should put yourself last **Lisa's and my**.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose to write this as:

> As outlined in our thesis, Lisa and I [found|said|revealed] ...

Other than the first two, the examples in JavaLatte's answer do not sound grammatically correct/normal to my ears.

Comment: So the answer to the question is that both are ungrammatical? Or simply not idiomatic?

Comment: I wasn't brought up to follow grammatical rules, so can't comment on that, but certainly they are not idiomatic.